# let $X =\lbrace (a_0, \cdots , a_n) \in S^n \mid \exists (x_1, \cdots , x_n) \in K, a_0 = a_1x_1 +\cdots+a_n x_n \rbrace $ is a closed

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact subset. Prove that
$X =\lbrace (a_0, \cdots , a_n) \in S^n  \mid \exists (x_1, \cdots , x_n) \in K, a_0 = a_1x_1 +\cdots+a_n x_n \rbrace $
is a closed subset of the unit sphere.

I try understand what  is the set $X$ for it i try the case $n=1$ and then it follows in $S^1$ in the plane.

And $X=\lbrace (a_0, a_1) \in S^1  \mid \exists x_1 \in K, a_0 = a_1x \rbrace$ and chose
$K=[a,b]$ with $a<b$.
I note that $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)\in X$.Now I try characterize the points that lie in $X$ and in fact I suppose that $(x,y)\in X\subset S^1$ since $x^2+y^2=1$ then $x^2=1-y^2$ and $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ form here
$1-y^2 \geq 0$ then $1 \geq y^2$ it is $1 \geq y$.

We need that $x=yk$ for $k\in [a,b]$ WLOG suppose $0<a<b$

Now $$yk=\sqrt{1-y^2}$$ for $y\leq 1$
from here $$y^2k^2=1-y^2\Rightarrow (k^2+1)y^2=1 \Rightarrow y^2=\frac{1}{k^2+1}$$
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2+1}} >0, \therefore 0< \frac{1}{k^2+1}\leq 1$$

Then any $k\in [a,b]$ satisfaces the condition and the points that satisface are
$$X=\lbrace \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^2+1}},\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2+1}} \right) \mid k\in [a,b] \rbrace $$

Frome here I want show thaht $X$ is closed, and the more easy way is show that $X$ is compact.
But I can´t see why  is closed since . I think two ways of prove it

*Show that $X$ is compact*

*Show that $S^{n}\setminus X$ is open*

*Show that $X=\overline{X}*$

I think that the most easy way is ***Show that $X=\overline{X}$** But in case of see that $X$ contains their limit points(adherents points) I don´t see how continue with the general case.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Why should $(0,\pm 1)\in X$ --- have you tried it with $K=[10,100]$ or similar?

Comment: Yes, is clear that for $k\in [a,b]$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $(0,1)\in X$  but $(1,0)\not \in X$

Comment: So what is that $k\in[10,100]$ that will make $\pm 1=k\cdot 0$?

Comment: It depends if $0\in [a,b]$

Comment: I deleted the tag "covering-spaces" because it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Thanks  for the correction

Comment: Hint: A good way to show a set $X$ is closed: if $u_j \in X$ for $j=1,2,\dots$ and $u_j$ converges to $u$, then $u \in X$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\begin{aligned} X &= \lbrace (a_0, \cdots , a_n) \in S^n  \mid \exists (x_1, \cdots , x_n) \in K, a_0 = a_1x_1 +\cdots+a_n x_n \rbrace\\
&=\lbrace (a_0, \cdots , a_n) \in S^n  \mid \exists (x_1, \cdots , x_n) \in K, d((1,x_1, \dots, x_n), P(-a_0, a_1, \dots,  a_n)) = 0\rbrace\\
&= \lbrace (a_0, \cdots , a_n) \in S^n  \mid d(K_1, P(-a_0, a_1, \dots,  a_n)) = 0\rbrace
\end{aligned}$$

where $P(a_0, a_1, \dots,  a_n)$ stands for the plane of equation

$$a_0 \cdot 1 +a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n = 0$$ and $K_1$ for the compact $K_1=\lbrace (1, x_1, \dots, x_n) \mid (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in K \rbrace \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$.

The desired result will be proven, providing that we prove that the map defined on $S^n$ by $(a_0, \cdots , a_n) \mapsto d(K_1, P(-a_0, a_1, \dots,  a_n))$ is continuous.

Comment: For say the true I don´t understand the mayori of the things that you affirm, I will try to understand, thanks a lot for you advice